# How fix it: 42 vulnerabilities (3 low, 15 moderate, 24 high)?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

Here are my settings:

**My Environment and Versions:**
nodeJS: v14.18.1
npm: 8.1.1
expo-cli: 4.12.10
OS: MacOS Big Sur 11.6

**My package.json:**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.66.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

After **npm install** After this command I get a message like this:
[error message after npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCzOT.jpg)

**42 vulnerabilities (3 low, 15 moderate, 24 high)**

After this message I tried: **npm update --legacy-peer-deps**

And now i get: **31 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 23 high)**

When i try use **npm audit fix** i get this: [unable to resolve dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEiNV.jpg)

Here is the full text of the log:

```
# npm resolution error report

2021-10-26T12:26:46.860Z

While resolving: rcapp@undefined
Found: react@17.0.1
node_modules/react
  react@"17.0.1" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"17.0.2" from react-native@0.66.1
node_modules/react-native
  react-native@"^0.66.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "react",
    "version": "17.0.1",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "rcapp",
      "path": "/Users/maksimpaun/Desktop/sdaibox-terra/reclub/rcapp"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/react",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "17.0.1",
        "from": {
          "location": "/Users/maksimpaun/Desktop/sdaibox-terra/reclub/rcapp"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "17.0.1",
    "from": {
      "location": "/Users/maksimpaun/Desktop/sdaibox-terra/reclub/rcapp"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "17.0.2",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "react-native",
      "version": "0.66.1",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "rcapp",
        "path": "/Users/maksimpaun/Desktop/sdaibox-terra/reclub/rcapp"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/react-native",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "react-native",
          "spec": "^0.66.1",
          "from": {
            "location": "/Users/maksimpaun/Desktop/sdaibox-terra/reclub/rcapp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

So, after this i try use: **npm audit fix --legacy-peer-deps**, but it doesn't help.

The project itself seems to run without problems, but such a large number of errors worries me.

Please tell me how I can identify them and fix them.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

#### STEP 1

Delete the `node_modules` folder.

#### STEP 2

Update the packages to latest version. Change you `package.json` like this:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "^43.0.1 ",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.66.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.5",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8"
  },
```

#### STEP 3

Do `npm install`

#### STEP 4

Check if vulnerabilities are fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did everything as you described now i get:

`36 vulnerabilities (5 low, 8 moderate, 23 high)`